# Static/dynamic binding in Java

Tags: java, compilation, dynamic-binding, static-binding

I do have `class Person, class Student` and `Student extends Person`. As far as I understood, it goes the following with static binding:

```
class Person {
   talk(Person p) {
      print("Hi by person.");
   } 
}

class Student extends Person {
   talk(Student s) {
      print("Hi by stud.");
   }
}
```

Now if I instantiate and call method:

```
Person x = new Student();
talk(x);                      
// output: "Hi by person." because of static binding, am I right?
```

**My Question**:
What if only `class Student` has a method `talk(Student s)`. Now I call `talk(x)`. Since I usually should get `talk()` method from `class Person`, what happens when there is no such method?

EDIT: I tried to run it and it gives me an Compile Error. Ok, but why does this happen? I learned that the compiler will first go to the subclass and search for the method and if it's there, then it gets executed?

Comment: Did you try making that program?

Comment: I actually did not you are right, but regardless of the outcome, I am interested in the rule behind it as well.

Comment: @JushKillaB "Why?" what?

Comment: "_What if only class `Student` has a method `talk(Student s)`_" - have you tried this? Hint: does it compile?

Comment: Ran it, doesnt compile but I dont get it. Why does it not look for the `talk()` method in its subclass `class Student`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't exist dynamic binding for overloaded methods ...

and Student is a Person so method talk from Person invoked

Comment: This is rather far from being clear... For example "_`Student` is a `Person`_" is really meaning that the reference `x` is a reference to a `Person`, not that `Student extends Person`.